# Как вывести название подкатегории в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать вывод подкатегории в ссылку? Подкатегория является дочерним элементом основной категории. У меня почему-то выводится и основная и дочерняя в списке. Можно ли выводить последнюю вложенность категории, а не все полотно. Т.е. есть  `новости > мировые > пост`.
На странице поста выводить ссылку на категорию `мировые`.

Comment: Стоит подробней  показать/рассказать про " выводится и основная и дочерняя в списке". Что за список, как/чем сделан? Где выводится. Показать код, если это код. Это можно сделать отредактировав вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad Например, я нахожусь на странице поста, пост в совю очередь находится в рубрике мировые а рубрика мировые находится в рубрике новости, мне нужно сделать ссылку на рубрику мировые в теле поста. Те последнюю рубрику в которой лежит пост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[the_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2/the_category) Выводит ссылки на рубрики к которым принадлежит пост.  Должна быть внутри цикла Wordpress.

Вывод категории поста: `<?php the_category(); ?>`
Выведет `мировые` со ссылкой, если пост НЕ принадлежит категории `новости`, а только её дочерней - `мировые`.

Comment: Спасибо подходит, можно ли как-то задать класс? получается что функция выводит ссылку без класса

Comment: такой способ это нормально? function add_class_the_category($html){
     $postid = get_the_ID();
  $html = str_replace('<a','<a class="single__article__top__link"',$html);
  return $html;
 }
 add_filter('the_category','add_class_the_category');

Comment: а не борода, если новость находится в двух рубриках выводится вде рубрики.

Comment: Ну как бы естественно что если в двух, то обе выведет. А если в 10 - то все 10. Кому принадлежит - то и выведет.

Comment: ну хоть спасибо и на этом!

Comment: Скажите, можно ли выводтить просто имя категории, без ссылки, просто текст? как the_title например

Comment: `$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;`

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Comment: Помучаю вас еще с вопросами, функция <?php the_categroy();?> строит свою структуру ul > li > a , можно ли выводить только ссылки без обертки ul li?

Comment: Можно. в документации же всё написано, примеры даны.